# Iterate over associative arrays inside an indexed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, key, associative

I'm learning JS and have to do a trivia game, where each question has 4 possible answers. The questions are given to me in a string with "#", which separates the questions, and "@", which separates each question in its id, its text, and its correct answer.
For the answers I have a string with similar format: idQuestion@idAnswer@textOfAnswer#
I know I did it in a very precarious way (I'm using 4 arrays! ._.), but I can't figure another way to do it.
This is the code where I start from the string which contains the answers, and transform each answer in an "associative array", which is saved in an indexed answer... called `assocAnswers` (wtf xD):

```
var indexAnswers = strAnswers.split("#");
var auxArray = new Array ();
var auxArray2 = new Array();
var assocAnswers = new Array ();
for (var b=0; b<indexAnswers.length; b++){
    auxArray = indexAnswers[b].split("@");
    auxArray2 = {
        "idQuestion":auxArray[0],
        "idAnswer":auxArray[1],
        "txtAnswer":auxArray[2]
    }
    assocAnswers.push(auxArray2);
}
```

I want to know how can I manage to check if the value of idQuestion (which is the first key in each "associative array" that occupies one element of the indexed array) equals x number.
Once I checked that, I have to find the remaining 3 answers with also match the idQuestion, and display the four answers in a div (so I have to display the value of the key `txtAnswer`), each answer in a `<label>` inside a radio input, but *I think* I don't need help with the jQuery part. BTW, I haven't learned the for...in loop yet, so if anyone uses it for a possible solution, any explanation of that will be more than welcomed :P Thanks!

Edit: Some examples of the strQuestions in english (strAnswers remains in spanish):

```
var strQuestions = "1@How is a function without parameters declared?@2#"
+ "2@Which of the next invocations is right?@4#"
+ "3@Given a function: myFunction(a,b) Which is the correct invocation?@3#";

var strAnswers =
"1@1@ function:myFunction()#1@2@ function myFunction()#1@3@ declare myFunction()#1@4@ new myFunction#2@1@Resultado=myFunction#2@2@Call myFunction()#2@3@myFunction#2@4@Resultado=myFunction()#3@1@MiFuncion a,b#3@2@a=MiFuncion(b)#3@3@MiFuncion(x,y)#3@4@Ninguna de las anteriores#
```

Comment: Can you provide some same data that is being passed in?

Comment: I'll post the data, but it's in spanish...
Answers of the same question have the same idQuestion but different idAnswer, being the last from 1 to 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got pretty lazy while writing it, but this fiddler will show how you can parse it and this turns it into an array of objects so you can work with it easier.  There is also a method to easily find an element based on a collection and the id of the element.

There probably is a better way to for the `for` loops but I can't think of it off the top of my head at the moment.  I will update it if I can remember.

The [JSfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/tj8nm/4/).

Note: The anwserId is stored in the `.key` property

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand your problem correctly...

> I know I did it in a very precarious way (I'm using 4 arrays! ._.),
>   but I can't figure another way to do it.

```
var data = '1@1@hello#2@1@foo#1@2@world';

var questions = data.split('#').map(function(q) {
  q = q.split('@');
  return {
    idQuestion: q[0],
    idAnswer: q[1],
    text: q[2]
  };
});
```

Now you have your object with key:value pairs. This is how you can filter by any criteria:

```
var filteredQuestions = questions.filter(function(q) {
  return q.idQuestion == 1;
});

console.log(filteredQuestions); //=> [{...text: "hello"}, {...text: "world"}]
```

Comment: Didn't know the `.map` and `.filter`. If I just copy paste your code on jsFiddle, changing the `console.log` for an `alert`, it displays `[object, Object], [object, Object]`. From what I understood of your code, shouldn't it display `"hello", "world"`, as you wrote in the commented part? Thanks!

Comment: `filteredQuestions` contains the two objects that were filtered by `idQuestion`. If you want the text of those questions then you'd have to use `map` again and return the `text`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to fully understand your code (the way you declared the functions and the methods used are **totally** new for me) and implement it somehow. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var indexAnswers = strAnswers.split("#");
var auxArray = new Array ();
var auxArray2 = new Array();
var assocAnswers = new Array ();
for (var b=0; b<indexAnswers.length; b++){
    auxArray = indexAnswers[b].split("@");
    if (auxArray[0].toString() == someId.toString()) {
        ... Fill your page
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, I don't think so. If I understood correctly, your code saves all the final data in an indexed array, doesn't it? 
Like: 
`auxArray = (1,1,text,1,2,text...);`
I think it would be more efficient if I use an "associative array". Thanks anyway! :D

Comment: wasn't actually doing the storage here, just the test to find the item that you want to display on the page, by comparing the [0] with the x number(someId). But hey, there is already a good answer here from elclanrs